# Anti Theft Device with bluetooth compatibility

Tags: bluetooth

Is there any Good Anti theft gadget with Bluetooth compatibility for Windows Phone??

There are gadgets compatible with Android/iOS.

Check this link [Click here](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Anti-Loss-Gadget-Anti-Theft-Device-work-with-Iphone-Samsung-Lg-Sony-Moto-/301248603344?_trksid=p2054897.l4275)

Comment: Do you mean like the [Treasure Tag](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/accessory/ws-2/)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any Bluetooth LE device that has an "Alert on device when disconnected" feature.

I use the Kensington Alarm Tag for iOS my Lumia 1520, [here is the link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00APEG8N4). Although, because I am a developer, I was able to write an app for the tag to alert me.

If you're not a dev, I recommend @RowlandShaw's suggestion because the Treasure Tag app will let you enable "alert on device" option.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this reference :-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn423914(v=vs.85).aspx

Also you can get them cheap from here :-

http://www.groupon.co.in/deals/shopping/cpcn-self-timer-finder-and-bluetooth-selfie/692067?p=9&nlp=&CID=IN_CRM_1_0_0_21&utm_source=channel_occasions-deals&utm_medium=email&sid=90d8c585-777b-4b71-8f1e-5dcdddb8ca03&division=shopping&uh=5fac801f-3983-4830-b06d-df7300fd8827&date=20152101&sender=rm&s=body&c=deal_img&d=deal-page

I was also trying to find the same. As Lance suggested you can use the link above for even getting some sample code for a device which has a heart beat sensor (commonly used in the bands being advertised these days).

Comment: Please improve your answer. Imagine these links can go offline and the answer will be lost. And the item you had mention should be explained here, not a lonely big URL.